# Response.Redirect and causes System.Threading.ThreadAbortException?

Tags: c#, webforms

I am working on a web application. Can someone help me to redirect after login using `Response.Redirect` I tried any solutions that i have seen on the internet but no solutions worked for me.

Cant fix this problem since I started 2 weeks ago.

```
public void checkSessionIfNull(string location) {
    try
    {
        location   = "../examples/login.html";
        if (HttpContext.Current.Session[AppUser] != null){
            HttpContext.Current.Response.RedirectPermanent(location,false);
             HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
        }
        else{
            returntoLoginIfSessionisNull(HttpContext.Current.Session[AppUser]);
        }
    }catch (ThreadAbortException ex1){
        Console.WriteLine(ex1.Message.ToString());
    }catch (Exception ex) {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message.ToString());
    }
}
```

Thanks , Regardds

Comment: a) When testing, **never** use `RedirectPermanent`. If you make a mistake, the browser will 'remember' the mistake for a long time. b) Are you **sure** the above code throws `ThreadAbortException`? Can you test it again to be sure?

Comment: If you have a new question, create a new one. Don't edit this one.